# Apply conditional formatting to subsequent cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have been trying to find a way to highlight a column when the date in row 2 is within the current week. I've done this by using:

1. `=(WEEKNUM(A$2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY()))` in A1:AS1
2. `=date(xxxx,xx,xx)` in A2:AS2 (and then `=A2+7` in subsequent cells)
3. apply conditional formatting to cells A3:A60

The only reason I've used the first step is because I couldn't get combining the formula to work in conditional formatting.

When I highlight A1:A60 and "drag" them to the right, the "apply formatting to" field contains ALL of the cells highlighted, and the custom formula only looks at cell A1.

How do I apply conditional formatting to columns B:AS and have it relate to cell 1 of any given column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understood your question. But if you want to color a row (in the range B:AS) when column 1 of that row contains a date that falls in the same week as today, then ..

1. set up the range to B1:AS1000
2. use this custom formula

   =WEEKNUM($A1)=WEEKNUM(TODAY())

Change ranges to suit and see if that works ?

EDIT: Based on the comment below

1. set up the range to A3:A60
2. Use this custom formula

   =WEEKNUM($A$2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY())

Comment: Thanks for the reply - it's actually the cells A3:A60 I want to colour, when the cell A2 contains a date in the current week - I used WEEKNUM to get a TRUE/FALSE in cell A1, and then tried to set the formatting based on that value, but with no luck.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks
The only issue now, is how to copy this formatting on to each subsequent block of cells and have it refer to the 2nd row of the block.

When I drag the cells, it just expands the range, and keeps the custom formula with A2.

Comment: why do you need to copy ? If you want to apply that to a range (e.g: A:D) you can change the range to A3:D60 and use as a custom formula =WEEKNUM(A$2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY()) (note the difference) ???

Comment: Thank you so much - I clearly need to look into how the $ works.